# Upgrading Spark 2.4.5 to Spark 3.3.2 Causing Shuffle Failures

Tags: scala, apache-spark, upgrade

We use to run our jobs on **Spark 2.4.5 Standalone cluster**. We upgraded our cluster to **Spark 3.3.2** and started running our jobs on the new cluster after upgrading our App code to Spark 3.3.2 as well. Most of the jobs work fine. But, some of the jobs are failing due to Shuffle Errors. I tried to get help checking known issues. But, we didn't find any resources helpful. I am sure it is **not related to Memory issues, Executor failures, Worker failures which I typically solved by increasing the resources**.

**As per exception, The executors failing to fetch the Shuffle files from the worker node.** We are not sure whether it is from remote or local. Either way, We are not seeing failures on all jobs. Only some jobs are failing on a daily basis.

The Jobs that are failing with default config are working by enabling **External Shuffle Service**. We would like to disable External Shuffle Service and run the jobs with default config for scalability reasons.

Can someone please kindly help us investigate the issue. Thanks. Below is the exception we are seeing on failed jobs.

```
"2022-07-14T15:21:26.781+0000" [WARN] {"logger":"scheduler.TaskSetManager", Lost task 3.0 in stage 40.1 (TID 82) (10.194.39.216 executor 11): FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(16, 10.194.39.216, 37299, None), shuffleId=24, mapIndex=2, mapId=47, reduceId=4, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException
    at org.apache.spark.errors.SparkCoreErrors$.fetchFailedError(SparkCoreErrors.scala:312)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:1166)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:904)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/spark-c3eebc32-7801-45e8-b1f1-62dbd729df98/executor-251a979e-f27d-413a-ae48-3153508c55be/blockmgr-532637ac-156e-4e7e-9934-6e15bdaf9ed9/2f/shuffle_24_47_0.index
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.getBlockData(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:582)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getHostLocalShuffleData(BlockManager.scala:673)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchHostLocalBlock(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.$anonfun$fetchMultipleHostLocalBlocks$2(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:673)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.$anonfun$fetchMultipleHostLocalBlocks$2$adapted(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:672)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.forall(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:85)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.forall$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.forall(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.$anonfun$fetchMultipleHostLocalBlocks$1(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.$anonfun$fetchMultipleHostLocalBlocks$1$adapted(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:671)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.forall(Iterator.scala:955)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.forall$(Iterator.scala:953)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.forall(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.forall(IterableLike.scala:77)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.forall$(IterableLike.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.forall(Iterable.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.fetchMultipleHostLocalBlocks(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:671)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.$anonfun$fetchHostLocalBlocks$6(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:645)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.$anonfun$fetchHostLocalBlocks$6$adapted(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:640)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.HostLocalDirManager.$anonfun$getHostLocalDirs$1(BlockManager.scala:156)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.BlockStoreClient$1.onSuccess(BlockStoreClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:196)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:142)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
)}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/spark...` - check whether due to upgrade, Spark app temp files are being cleared before job completion causing job failure.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing identical errors to what you saw and was able to fix them by adding:

```
"spark.shuffle.useOldFetchProtocol": "true"
```

to spark configs.